# ggplot2: how to assign a graduated color legend and add shaded relief background to a map

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps, legend

Using this [data.frame (you can download it from here)](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/n835nrhss97k4ml/AADj4-N-3WOD5z2QcQ1iH_u9a?dl=0) and the code below

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(ggmap)

setwd("<path to df.csv file>")
df <- read.csv("df.csv")

ggplot(df, aes(x=long, y= lat)) + 
  geom_polygon(aes(x=long, y= lat, group= Site1, fill = mean),
               color = "black",
               size = 0.1)+
  scale_fill_distiller(name=bquote(atop("Mean Annual",
                                        "Concentration" ~ (mg~L^{-1}))),
                       palette = 
                         "OrRd"
                       , 
                       breaks = pretty_breaks(n = 5),
                       direction = 1)+
  facet_wrap(~year, ncol=4)+
  theme_nothing(legend = TRUE)
```

I got this plot

[image]

I want to:

1) add a shaded relief background to my plot.

2) create a graduated color legend where I can assign the breaks in values (e.g.  0.02-0.07, 0.07-0.12, 0.12, 0.17..)

I can do this in basic R through assigning breaks in the legend. For example

```
q <- cut(df$ParameterA, breaks=c(0, 0.02, 0.20, 0.07, 0.12, 0.17, 0.22, 0.25)), include.lowest=T, labels=labs)
legend(legend = c("<0.02", "0.02-0.07", "0.07-0.12", "0.12-0.17", "0.17-0.22", ">0.22"), fill = levels(q))
```

But, I don't know how to do this using `ggplot2`

Your suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "shaded relief background". So a color gradient? In what way is it a relief? And over the whole plot, or per frame?

Comment: @MikeWise

Thanks Mike. Please, follow this link to find an example of shaded relief maps. I want it to be a background per frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a graduated color legend, you need to `cut` your data in the data frame before calling `ggplot`, like this:

```
df$mean_cut <- cut(df$mean, 
                   c(0, 0.02, 0.20, 0.07, 0.12, 0.17, 0.22, 0.25), 
                   include.lowest = TRUE)
```

I added an `, Inf` in your cut `breaks` because I noticed the bottom polygon in your 2011 facet wasn't getting a value assigned.

Then you can fill using the new data column:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=long, y= lat)) + 
geom_polygon(aes(x=long, y= lat, group= Site1, fill = mean_cut),
             color = "black",
             size = 0.1)
```

Then you'll need to use a discrete scale like `scale_fill_brewer`:

```
  scale_fill_brewer(name=bquote(atop("Mean Annual",
                                 "Concentration" ~ (mg~L^{-1}))),
                    type = "seq",
                    palette = "OrRd",
                    direction = 1)
```

I think you could add basemaps fairly easily with `ggmap`, but I don't know the location of your data so its hard to give an example.

See https://www.nceas.ucsb.edu/~frazier/RSpatialGuides/ggmap/ggmapCheatsheet.pdf for a tutorial on adding the basemap to your plot. It would be something along the lines of:

```
myMap <- get_map(location, source, maptype)
ggmap(myMap) +
  geom_polygon(...) +
  scale_fill_brewer(...) +
  facet_wrap(...) +
  theme_nothing()
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and help. 

Following your suggestion, I tried adding a terrain base map using the code below but it didn't work

myLocation <- c(174.69, -40.37, 176.44, -38.93)

myMap <- get_map(location = myLocation, 
                 source = "google", 
                 maptype = "terrain",
                 crop = FALSE)


ggmap(myMap)+ 
rest of the code

It plotted the terrain map without the polygons on top. Any suggestions to fix this?

Comment: The coordinates of your polygons are not in lat/long, are they?

Comment: No, they are in New Zealand Transverse Mercator NZTM 2000.